# TypeError: (0, _firestore.collection)((0, _(...)Id : ''no message'), 'message').orderBy is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get only the most new message of the conversation from Firebase, but I don't get why I get an error.

**React Native:**

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const messagesRef = query(collection(doc(db, 'chats', queryId?queryId:'wala'), 'message').orderBy('time', 'asc').limit(refresh))
  const SnapsMSg = onSnapshot(messagesRef, (snaps) => {
    const msgElemet = snaps.docs.map((map) => ({ ...map.data() }));
    setMessages(msgElemet);
  });
  return () => SnapsMSg();
}, [queryId,refresh]);
```

How can ideal with such error like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the modern JavaScript SDK, `orderBy` and `limit` are no longer members of a `CollectionReference` or `Query` object. They are their own independent functions as covered by the [Cloud Firestore Order and Limit Data documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

```
import { query, collection, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const chatDocRef = doc(db, 'chats', queryId ? queryId : 'wala');
  const chatMessagesColRef = collection(chatDocRef, 'message');
  const latestChatMessagesQuery = query(
    chatMessagesColRef,
    orderBy('time', 'asc'),
    limit(refresh)
  )

  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(latestChatMessagesQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
    const msgArray = querySnapshot.docs.map((map) => ({ ...map.data() }));
    setMessages(msgArray);
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, [queryId, refresh]);
```